# Sharepoint 2013 - javascript to show hide not responding

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sputility

I have been using this show/hide SPUtility code for some time without problem.
IN my new custom form I have tried unsuccessfully for the code to 'activate'.
I am able to see the code within the WebPartPages:WebPartZone section of the custom form.

I am using it with other webpart with other script blocks.
I am not sure if anyone has had a similar problem

N.B. other script blocks contain script to change button name also script to change text when using 'other' in a choice field.

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.2-min.js"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/sputility.js"></script>    
<script javascript="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var IntExtField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Was anyone injured or ill');    
            var showOrHideField = function() {
        var IntExtFieldValue = IntExtField.GetValue();    
 if(IntExtFieldValue === 'No') {
          SPUtility.HideSPField('Person or persons');       
          SPUtility.HideSPField('Source of Information'); 
       } 
 if(IntExtFieldValue === 'Yes') {
          SPUtility.ShowSPField('Person or persons');
          SPUtility.ShowSPField('Source of Information');
      }
        };
    showOrHideField();
    $(IntExtField.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check your browser console if any errors are there.

Comment: Agree, use the F12 debugger and see if there are any errors on the Console tab after you refresh the page. BTW your script tag is wrong. You have "JavaScript=text/javascript". Should be "language=text/javascript". The browser probably ignores this but check that out.

Comment: If only it were that easy. No errors. Thanks for the tag correction.

Comment: Syntax type="text/javascript"